# Limes is not a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures on $(X, A)$. Let's assume for all $B \in A$ the limes $\mu(B) = $lim$\mu_n(B) \in [0, \infty]$ exist. Then $\mu$ don't have to be a measure on $(X, A)$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_n=\delta_{n}$ be Dirac mass at $n$. Then, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu_n([k-1,k))=0$ for each $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(\mathbb{R})=1,$ so $\sigma$-additivity might fail.

Comment: I wonder: does it work if you're on a compact, or I guess finite measure, space?

Comment: These measures *are* finite. And you could just observe $\delta_{1/n}$ on $[0,1]$. The exact same thing happens.

Comment: Oh right, I guess my question doesn't make sense then.